# Output database text value into div

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to output values saved in my database into a div field, however the data does not seem to come out, could anyone explain to me why?

```
<div>
<?php
        $host="localhost"; // Host name 
        $username="root"; // Mysql username 
        $password="root"; // Mysql password 
        $db_name="Database"; // Database name 

        mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
        mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

        $result=mysql_query("SELECT from `posts`");
        $num=mysql_numrows($result);
        $i=0;
        while ($i < $num) {
            echo $result[$i];
            $i++;
        }
        ?>
</div>
```

Above is the code I have inside the div tag. So my question why does my echo not work?

Comment: 1) Don't use `mysql_` functions. They're deprecated. Switch to MySQLi or PDO. 2) Turn on error reporting. 3) There's no function named `mysql_numrows()`.

Comment: @Deepu No errors come up the page just reloads without the div information.

Comment: `$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts");`

Comment: You aren't selecting anything. SELECT * (all) from `posts` or SELECT (some column name) from `posts` will help display info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the way to do that, you may use like this:

```
//$result=mysql_query("SELECT from `posts`"); <- this query is wrong. 
if ($result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts"))
{
    $num=mysql_num_rows($result);

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       echo $row['key']; // <- you must set the field name of your query here
   } 
}
else // This if will show you when any query error is thrown.
{
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

Your original query is wrong. You may get an error because `SELECT FROM` is not valid. You **have** to specify a list of fields, a function or `*` to get all fields of the table.

The you may use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php), [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) or [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) in order to *fetch* the received data from the query.

Plus, I have added an `if` in your query command in order to get any mysql error thrown in your query execution. Using that you'll never be confuse about *what happened here*.

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**: As @SpiderLinked said(Thank you dude), `mysql_numrows()` does not exists. You have to use [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to get query result count.

Answer (score 1):

```
"SELECT from `posts`"
```

is not a valid query.

This would be:

```
"SELECT * FROM `posts`"
```

Also the following won't pull any results from your database:

```
while ($i < $num) {
    echo $result[$i];
    $i++;
}
```

You would need to loop around the results as you fetch them:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['field'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors with your code...first....you do not give the result of the query to any variable...second...your query is wrong...third... there is no such function as mysql_numrows()....here is an example of what it should look like:

```
<div>
  <?php
    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="root"; // Mysql username 
    $password="root"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="Database"; // Database name 

    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts") or die (mysql_error()); //added die for debugging purposes
    while ($num=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $num['COLUMN NAME HERE!'];
    }
    ?>
```

Also...please stop using mysql_ while it is deprecated...

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
<div>
<?php
    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="root"; // Mysql username 
    $password="root"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="Database"; // Database name 

    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts");
    $num=mysql_numrows($result);
    if($num>0) {
        echo $num." rows returned";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row['key'];
        }
    } else {
        echo "No Rows Returned";
    }

    ?>
</div>
```